# Setting up cryptographic key between Arduino and React Native app

Tags: react-native, arduino, cryptography, aes, key-generator

I am new to Arduino and working on a project to pass cryptographic keys between Arduino (ESP8266) and a React Native app. On the ESP8266 side I am using [arduino crypto library](https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/crypto.html)  and for React Native I am using [react-native-crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-crypto-js). The encryption doesn't seem to do the right thing and returns garbage. So, as a first step I was trying to pass the key from Arduino into the mobile app (using the bluetooth HC-05). The following code was used in the arduino side:

```
void getConnected() {
  // wait till someone try to connect to the user
  if (btSerial.available() > 0) {
    String message =  btSerial.readString();
    if(message == "Hello") {
      Serial.println("user trying to connect");
      byte key[32];
      device.getKey(key);
      Serial.println((char*)key);
      btSerial.write((char*)key);
    }
  }
}
```

The key is generated using `RNG.rand(key, sizeof(key))` and I also printed the generated bytes separately and it is something like:

137 224 186 115 0 0 0 0 172 228 254 63 131 53 32 64 208 218 255 63 13 0 0 0 172 228 254 63 48 70 32 64

As you see above, since there are 0s in the bytes, the code in the React Native app is only getting the first 4 bytes, and the remaining is ignored as it is thinking the 5th byte to be the end of string. 
The code used in the App is as below:

```
  async setup(deviceId) {
    console.log('connecting');
    await BluetoothSerial.connect(deviceId);
    console.log('connected');
    await BluetoothSerial.write('Hello');
    setTimeout(async () => {
      let key = await BluetoothSerial.readFromDevice();
      console.log(key);
    }, 3000);
    // const input = await BluetoothSerial.readFromDevice();
    return true;
  }
```

I would really appreciate some pointers. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: The error is in treating the random byte values as characters. Bytes are not characters, even if they are represented as `char` values in C & C style languages that copy that bad idiom.

Comment: Thanks Maarten, I am not sure how else to do it. Can you please guide me. I am very new to Arduino.

Comment: Either you have to use arrays and array sizes or if you need strings you can base64 encode the ciphertext. For debugging hexadecimals are probably best, although generally you already got that if you display the bytes into a memory viewer in a C / C++ debugger.

Comment: thanks @MaartenBodewes, I will try it out and let you know. Thanks for the pointer.